# CLBeacons in app suspended state

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, cllocationmanager, ibeacon

What I am trying to achieve is described in the following steps

1.User opens the app, navigates blah blah blah
 2.User presses the home button, the app shuts itself
 3.A background task for detecting CLbeacons starts. On every detection, A `UILocalNotification` is fired immediately, so as to make the user aware that a beacon has been discovered.

Now what happens with me

1. I open the app, navigate then press the home button to shut the app
2. The phone slowly darkens itself, i.e it goes to the slide to unlock state. Here no notification gets fired; Hell, the `CLLocationManger's` method `-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region` doesn't get called at all.
3. The phone goes to sleep. I slide open the phone to awake it; Immediately multiple `UIlocalNotifications enter.

Can anyone explain to me why is this happening?

```
//
//  AppDelegate.m
//  Beacon Proximity
//
//  Created by Debanjan Chakraborty on 7/15/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Debanjan Chakraborty. All rights reserved.
//

#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "CustomerRegViewController.h"
#import "IntialViewController.h"
#import "BeaconProduct.h"
#import "DBManager.h"
#import "APLDefaults.h"
#import "ScanViewController.h"


typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, BeaconType)
{
    Check,
    Bundle
};

@interface AppDelegate ()<CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@property CLLocationManager *locationAppManager;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger localNotificationCount;
//@property (nonatomic,strong) UILocalNotification *localNotification;
//@property (nonatomic) NSTimer *timerForNotifier;


@end

@implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"])
    {
        // app already launched
    }
    else
    {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];


        [self entryDatabase];

    }

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];


    UILocalNotification *notification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];

    if (notification)
    {
        NSLog(@" aache ?");
//        self.localNotificationCount = 0;
        UIAlertView *aw = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Case 1" message: notification.alertBody delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [aw show];
    }
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;

    return YES;
}
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {

    NSString *token = [[deviceToken description] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
    token = [token stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    NSLog(@"content---%@", token);

}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)err {

    NSLog(@"Error %@",err.localizedDescription);

}
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    if(![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"])
    {
         NSLog(@" Will REsign and initialise");

    }
    else
    {
      NSLog(@" Will REsign?");
    }
}
-(void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSLog(@" terminated");
}
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

    [self initialise];

    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber=0;


        for (NSUUID *uuid in [APLDefaults sharedDefaults].supportedProximityUUIDs)
        {
            CLBeaconRegion *region = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:uuid identifier:[uuid UUIDString]];
            [self.locationAppManager stopMonitoringForRegion:region];
        }
    self.locationAppManager = nil;

}
-(void)insert:(NSDate *)fire WithBeaconType:(BeaconType )beaconType ForBeacon:(CLBeacon *)beacon
{

    self.localNotificationCount++;

            UILocalNotification *localNotification = [UILocalNotification new];

            localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;

            localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber =self.localNotificationCount;

            localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate date];

            localNotification.alertAction = @"Show me";

            if(beaconType == Check)
            {
                localNotification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Check out new offers"];

                localNotification.alertAction = NSLocalizedString(@"Read Offer", nil);

            }
            else
            {
                localNotification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You've reached offers. Grab them before they expire soon"];

                localNotification.alertAction = NSLocalizedString(@"Grab Offer", nil);
            }



         [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];

         NSLog(@" should Notify minor is %d and major is %d",[beacon.minor integerValue],[beacon.major integerValue]);

         [[DBManager getSharedInstance] updateNotifiedTimeForBeacon:beacon];

}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{

}


- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];
    self.localNotificationCount = 0;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
}

-(UIViewController *)omegaScreen
{
    UIStoryboard *strybrd = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard" bundle:nil];
    NSString *viewId=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"custId"]?@"initial":@"custReg";
    UIViewController *controller=[strybrd instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:viewId];

    if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"custId"])
        [self initialise];

    return [viewId isEqualToString:@"initial"]?(IntialViewController *)controller:(CustomerRegViewController *)controller;
}



-(void)initialise
{
    self.locationAppManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationAppManager.delegate = self;


    for (NSUUID *uuid in [APLDefaults sharedDefaults].supportedProximityUUIDs)
    {
        NSLog(@" uuid is %@",uuid.UUIDString);
        CLBeaconRegion *region = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:uuid identifier:[uuid UUIDString]];
        region.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay=YES;
       [self.locationAppManager startMonitoringForRegion:region];
    }

    self.localNotificationCount = -1;
}
- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didStartMonitoringForRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
    NSLog(@" it did");
    if([region isKindOfClass:[CLBeaconRegion class]])
    {
        [self.locationAppManager requestStateForRegion:(CLBeaconRegion*)region];
    }

}
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didDetermineState:(CLRegionState)state forRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
    if (state == CLRegionStateInside)
    {
        //Start Ranging
        [manager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:(CLBeaconRegion*)region];
    }
}
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager*)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{

    if ([region isKindOfClass:[CLBeaconRegion class]])
    {
      [self.locationAppManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:(CLBeaconRegion*)region];
    }
}
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region
{

//    if([self runningInBackground])
//    {
//        NSLog(@" didRangeBeacons in App Delegate");

        for (CLBeacon *beacon in beacons)
        {
            if([[DBManager getSharedInstance]shouldNotifyFor:beacon])
            {
                BeaconType type;
                if([beacon.major integerValue]==0)
                {
                    type = Check;
                }
                else
                {
                    type = Bundle;
                }
                [self insert:[NSDate date]WithBeaconType:type ForBeacon:beacon];
            }
        }
//    }
}
-(BOOL) runningInBackground
{
    UIApplicationState state = [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState;
    BOOL result = (state == UIApplicationStateBackground);
    return result;
}
-(void)resetStatus
{
    NSLog(@" timer has been fired");
}

-(void)entryDatabase
{

        NSMutableArray *localArray = [NSMutableArray new];
        BeaconProduct *bP1 = [[BeaconProduct alloc] initWithProductSku:@"1" andId:@"1" andbTitle:@"BeaconAdTitle1" andDescription:@"Description1" andCurrency:@"Rupees" andSmallImage:@"Shampoo" andLargeImage:@"Shampoo" andPrice:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:700]];
        BeaconProduct *bP2 = [[BeaconProduct alloc] initWithProductSku:@"2" andId:@"1" andbTitle:@"BeaconAdTitle2" andDescription:@"Description2" andCurrency:@"Rupees" andSmallImage:@"conditionerFree" andLargeImage:@"conditionerFree" andPrice:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:200]];
        BeaconProduct *bP3 = [[BeaconProduct alloc] initWithProductSku:@"3" andId:@"2" andbTitle:@"BeaconAdTitle3" andDescription:@"Description3" andCurrency:@"Rupees" andSmallImage:@"soap" andLargeImage:@"soap" andPrice:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:20.50]];
        BeaconProduct *bP4 = [[BeaconProduct alloc] initWithProductSku:@"4" andId:@"3" andbTitle:@"BeaconAdTitle4" andDescription:@"Description4" andCurrency:@"Rupees" andSmallImage:@"shirt" andLargeImage:@"shirt" andPrice:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:250]];

        [localArray addObject:bP1];
        [localArray addObject:bP2];
        [localArray addObject:bP3];
        [localArray addObject:bP4];

        [[DBManager getSharedInstance] insertBeaconProduct:localArray];


}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should post your code so we can explain this definitively, but it sounds like you simply have `region.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay = YES;` when setting up your region.  When you have that option set, you will get an extra callback to your region entry callback from `CLLocationManager` every time you illuminate the display.

**EDIT:** After seeing the code, I also noticed that the app starts monitoring when it is about to to the background, then stops it when it goes back into the foreground.  I suspect this may be complicating the issue and giving you extra callbacks causing extra notifications.   It doesn't look like there is any reason to keep stopping and restarting monitoring.  I would suggest you simply set up monitoring of your beacon regions when the app starts up, and leave monitoring going.   This combined with setting region.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay=NO should prevent the multiple notifications.

**SECOND EDIT:** As to point (2), you should understand that you generally **CANNOT** range in the background at all.  Once your app leaves the foreground, you can only get callbacks to `didRangeBeacons: inRegion:` for about five seconds, at which time such callbacks stop until the app is woken up again.  One way you can wake it up is by transitioning from being in/out of a beacon region using the monitoring APIs.  However, you should understand that in the background, these transitions are not always instantaneous and can take up to 15 minutes.  [See here for details.](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2013/11/13/ibeacon-monitoring-in-the-background-and-foreground.html)

Comment: I added my code but I couldn't understand what you meant. I have region.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay = YES, I ran it with it, I ran without that code , yet the same behaviour was detected

Comment: Ok, but one thing what about step 2 that I am experiencing. CLbeacon doesn't gets detected when the app is in it's suspended state.

Comment: Thanks for the clarity David. One more thing. How can I place geofencing for CLBeacons? I tried with the accuracy provided, but the accuracy was too random, an arm-length distance from the beacon showed like 13-24m, which is too distorted. Since CLbeacons dodnot provide TXpower, the entire self calculation formula looks bleak.

Comment: You should probably post new questions here.  First, I do not see why you should get such poor distance estimates, so you should ask for help in improving this.  Second, I do not understand "How can I place geofencing for CLBeacons?" A new question with more detail would be helpful.

Comment: can you tell me what does proximity:3 +/- 12.92m, mean actually?

Comment: Where do you see "proximity:3 +/- 12.92m"?

Comment: Well, when I am trying to place a fencing for the CLbeacons I NSlog'd Clbeacon and got it. What I couldn't understand was , how to assure a good fencing for the CLbeacons.... I mean Airlocate shows 12-14m when clearly the beacon is just 3-4 meters away

Comment: Something is wrong with your beacon configuration.  This is a new topic, so please post a new question mentioning your beacon type and describing your calibration steps on the beacon (if any.)